# How to map one key to another in Object Array?

Tags: php, arrays, object

Let's say, I have an Array Object:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [uri] => sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/test-example.tpl.php
    [filename] => test-example.tpl.php
    [name] => test-example.tpl
)
```

Is there any way to map [uri] to [filename] ?

Example:

```
Array(
[sites/all/themes/bootstrap/templates/test-example.tpl.php] = [test-example.tpl.php]
)
```

Comment: `array( o$obj->uri => $obj->filename);`

Comment: glad to help ! good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that your object is named `$obj`:

```
$map = array( $obj->uri => $obj->filename );

var_dump( $map );
```

If you need to iterate through many elements, you can use `foreach`, but the logic is the same at all.